# Delphi forms derived from base form

Tags: forms, delphi, components

I have a delphi project which it will have multi forms and every form needs to override windows methods to handle windows messages (for example wndproc, wm_size ...)

Can i use a base form for it?

And if yes, How Can i use a base form for it so i can derive my forms from the base form and all the forms will have the same methods?

Will my derived forms from the base form have that methods automatically without declaring them?

Thanks

Comment: Of course, this is the whole purpose of inheriting classes. Forms are no exception. Delphi is best known for the nature of inheriting classes.

Comment: Search for *Visual Form Inheritance* in the documentation.

Comment: [Visual Form Inheritance](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+8+The+Architecture+of+Delphi+Applications/Visual+Form+Inheritance/)

Comment: @JerryDodge hi jerry, when i derived a form from a base form can i use the declared methods on the derived form or do i have to declare them again? For example i have a procedure in private section on base form which handles wm_size windows message, do i have to declare this method again in derived form?

Comment: @KenWhite thanks ken

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks remy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you inherit a form, it's just like inheriting other classes. By default, when you inherit a class, the *visible* methods are available for you to use. *visible* meaning, it depends on whether something is `private`, `public`, `published`, etc.

[Read here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Classes_and_Objects), particularly the part about `Visibility of Class Members`.

Assuming a method is visible in the inherited class, you can access it. In addition, you can override it if you need to make it behave differently, or if you need to catch / intercept something, etc. However, you can only override virtual methods.

For example...

```
type
  TBaseClass = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure DoSomething; virtual;
  end;

  TNewClass = class(TBaseClass)
  public
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;
```

You don't need to override it, but you can if you need to. You can [read more about it here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+8+The+Architecture+of+Delphi+Applications/Visual+Form+Inheritance/).

Comment: Jerry Thank you for the detailed explanation, it works, i can use derived forms and it is like a miracle :) i dont have to declare all the methods again and again on all the new forms

Comment: @Emreacikgoz You could also just try it for yourself and see if it works :-)

Comment: i did now and it does work :) but i wanted to ask before try it in case of i needed to do or learn some detail before i do it